# ES6 class construction

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I would like to ask you about class construction in JavaScript, ES6.
Is this ok to put class name inside constructor of other class which extends from "mother class"? (a bit confused...)

```
  class Brick {
    constructor(x,y,graphic,width,height,type,live, speed){
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.graphic = graphic
      this.width = width
      this.height = height
      this.type = type
      this.live = live
      this.speed = speed
  }
  print(){
      console.log(this.y)
      console.log(this.x)
      console.log(this.graphic)
      console.log(this.width)
      console.log(this.height)
      console.log(this.type)
      console.log(this.live)
    }
  init(){
    console.log('added to board')
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to make class wchih extends from Brick class so:

```
  class BrickRed extends Brick {
    constructor(Brick){
      super(...arguments)
      this.graphic = "red.jpg"
      this.live = 15
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure if it is ok, becouse I can't find any tutorial were it is presented like above. 
Exactly this two lines: `constructor(Brick)` and `super(...arguments)`

From tutorials which I saw, best (and only) option is to do like that:

```
class BrickBlue extends Brick {
    constructor(x,y,graphic,width,height,type,live, speed){
      super(x,y,graphic,width,height,type,live, speed)
      this.graphic = "blue.jpg"
      this.live = 10
    }
  }
```

But this looks ugly, and I want to improve it.

Comment: `constructor(Brick)` does nothing. Or more precisely it just says that the constructor takes a single parameter and you call that argument `Brick`. Since you never *use it* it ultimately doesn't matter. Or rather, you do, but you actually just pass all of `arguments`, so the parameter is ignored. You could have called it `foo` or `x` and it would have the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this ok to put class name inside constructor of other class which extends from "mother class"?

Nope. The correct way is your second snippet. However, if `BrickBlue` hardcodes some props, there's no need to pass them in the constructor:

```
class BrickBlue extends Brick {
    constructor(x,y,width,height,type,speed){
      super(x,y,"blue.jpg",width,height,type,10,speed)
    }
  }
```

If you're looking for something like

```
class BrickBlue extends Brick {
    constructor(args-of-Brick)
```

there's no such thing.

> But this looks ugly, and I want to improve it.

Yes, long argument lists are ugly, and since JS doesn't yet support named arguments, there's not much you can do. However, you could consider grouping related arguments into separate objects:

```
class Brick {
   constructor(position, graphic, size, type, behaviour)
```

where `position` is something like `{x:10, y:20}` etc

Another option is to provide the entire argument list an an object, thus imitating named arguments:

```
class Brick {
    constructor({x, y, graphic, width, height, type, live, speed}) {

...

new Brick({
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  graphic: ...
  ...
})
```

and in the derived class:

```
class BrickBlue extends Brick {
    constructor(args) {
        super({
            ...args,
            graphic: 'blue.jpg',
            live: 10
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'd go as far to say that `BlueBrick` doesn't need to be a child of `Brick`. Well, it *might* and if it does, passing the parameters up to the parent is the correct thing but it seems like it's something to leave up to a factory to give you rather than have a specific constructor. What if you want another object `BouncyBrick`? Can a brick be bouncy *and* blue? What if you also want `SecretBrick`? Can you have that blue an bouncy?

Comment: @VLAZ: sure, among pragmatic programmers inheritance is generally frowned upon these days, however most books and courses still consider it a vital part of the OOP so I guess we have to deal with it for the time being ;)